# Create custom hooks state in react and Manipulate global state from everywhere without using any third party state management library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**You can get**, reference here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cufbw4?file=models%2FTodoState.ts)

I have one folder file `todoState.ts` in `models` folder of project. This `todoState.ts` used for managing global state of application using custom hooks. I need to perform following tasks on global `todoState.ts`..

1. Add new State
2. Remove state
3. update state

**here is code of `todoState.ts`.**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const todoState = (todo?, callback?) => {
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState([todo]);

      useEffect(()=>{
          setTodos(todo);
      },[])

    return [{todos, setTodos}];
}
```

**Now,** I have Two user defined components which are dependent on globalState. which are 1. `<TodoForm />` and `<TodoListLineItem />`

**Both** of above component is rendered inside `index.tsx`.

How can I manage global state from all the components including `index.tsx` , `<TodoForm />` , `<TodoListLineItem />`. **Here**...

1. `<TodoForm />` , is used to add to tasks to list.
2. `<TodoListLineItem />`, is used to display all added tasks from TodoForm component. when user hover over to each todo list item then user can able to remove perticular tasks-item from global management state.

**Which** one is best and reusable way to implement this global management state feature?

How one component changed state from A to B is reflected on related component by just manipulating global state object of application. If I put `useState([])` into `index.tsx` then it will works well, But I want to manage state from `TodoState.ts` file. Thank You.

export default todoState;

Comment: Not 100% sure, but: use the hook in index.ts, and pass required props down to the components. Just like basic React. Why do you think this would work differently?

Comment: @ChrisG I do not want to pass state from index.tsx to all components. rather each component is updating global state separately.

Comment: If you don't want to pass data down through the tree, use a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead.

Comment: @ChrisG suppose, in `<TodoForm />` component add button is click to add new state, now how can I add new state to global file and after adding state to global, `<TodoListLineItem  />` component gets new new state and updates value.

Comment: @ChrisG can you give small working demo of  `Context` using one addition  of state? It would be better for me to understand it properly.

Comment: I am not in urgent mode. Thank you for your time being. Does stackoverflow charges any amount here to help other community member ?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally** , I found and learned New concepts for React-Context API. You can checkout here [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cufbw4?file=models%2FTodoState.tsx)

To manage global states React provides context-api. Use only when you have multiple level of component properties pass down in component tree from Top to bottom. I used very small example to understand context api for my different use-case.

**First** of all we need to use two context..

1. createContext [ used to create global state context ]
2. useContext    [ used to get states from context from child component ].

**To work** with Context I created one `<context.Provider>` component. and all state management tasks are done with only this component level only. all child component just send events of what to do. and global context of provider component changes accordingly.

**firstly**, Create context..

```
export interface ItodoContext{
  todoState? : Itodo[];
  addNewTodoState?: (state?: string) => void;
  removeTodoItemByIndex? : (index?: number) => void;
}

export const todoContext = createContext<ItodoContext[]>([{}]);
```

As, I am using React-Typescript functional component, as per Interface of context i defined all tasks of states. I passed all TodoState, function to manipulate TodoState like addNewTodoState, removeTodoItemByIndex.

then create Provider of context..

```
const allTodoStates = {
  todoState,
  addNewTodoState,
  removeTodoItemByIndex
}

return(
  <todoContext.Provider value = { [allTodoStates]}>      
     {props.children}
  </todoContext.Provider>
)
```

Then I set Provider as parent component in tree in index.tsx component like this..

```
 const App: FC = () => {
 return (
   <div className="h-100 w-100">
     <TodoStateProvider>
       <Navbar />
       <div className="container">
         <TodoForm />  
         <TodoListLineItem />
       </div>
     </TodoStateProvider>
   </div>
 );  
}
```

See above all components now child of `<TodoStateProvider>` parent component.

When I need to add new state to context is inside `<TodoForm>` and how we can add state is as below code...

```
const [{addNewTodoState}] = useContext(todoContext);

const sendTodoItem = (e) => {
      addNewTodoState(todoInput.trim());
}
```

and so on.. provider component has `value` property, and we can get those properties from child using useContext() hook. as we used above. See full working demo I have attached in above StackBlitz Link.